# Open CV - Is there is a way dispatch a method, by the underline pixel type?

Tags: c++, opencv, generic-programming

I open an image using imread(), getting a cv::Mat instance.
I wish to apply a function on this matrix, by its underline pixel type.
I wish to know if there is a Dispatch() function in openCV?
Here is a code sample.

```
FindFeature(cv::Mat_<Vec3b>& image) 
{
    image.forEach<Vec3b>([](Vec3b &p, const int * position) -> void 
    { p[0] /= 2; p[1] /= 2; p[2] /= 2;});
}

FindFeature(cv::Mat_<uchar>& image) 
{
    image.forEach<uchar>([](uchar &p, const int * position) -> void 
    { p /= 2; });
}

template<typename Pixel>
void FindFeature(cv::Mat_<Pixel>& image)
{
     // we don't know how to work on any other image type
     throw std::runtime_exception("unsupported image type");
}

void main()
{
    int flags = CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR | CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH
    cv::Mat image = imread("c:\image.jpg", flags);
    Dispatch(FindFeature, image);
}
```

Here you can see I handle differently grayscale and RGB images.

Comment: No, but you can load the image with `IMREAD_COLOR`, and it will always be CV_8UC3. Or you can just switch over the image `type`

Comment: It will be CV_8UC3, even if the picture is 255 gray scale?

Comment: Yes, the 3 channels will be equal.

Comment: You should probably better explain what you want to do inside `FindFeature`. because there are a few solution to this.

Comment: At the end, I need to process the image, and its all boil down to iterate the pixels.
To do it in an efficient manner, I have to work with `cv:Mat_<Pixel>` so I have the actual type. this is what I get inside these handlers.

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear, the difference between the image types, and their handlers.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33154287/5008845)